# How to prove that a partition of a set is a monomorphism in the category of sets

Tags: category-theory, integer-partitions, monomorphisms, pullback

I am having some trouble proving exercise 4.23 in the book "Sets for Mathematics" by Lawvere and Rosebrugh.

The problem is to prove that from a partition $p:A \rightarrow I$, which is defined there as a morphism $p$ which is a surjection/epimorphism with $A$ as domain. Taking a pullback, labelled $R_p$, of $p$ along itself should then give a monomorphism $(p_0,p_1):R_p \rightarrow A \times A$, which is the definition of being a relation on $A$, where $p_0:R_p \rightarrow A$ and $p_1:R_p \rightarrow A$ are the respective morphisms coming from taking the pullback of $p$ along itself such that $p p_0 = p p_1$:

My work so far is:

Let $t_0,t_1 : T \rightarrow R_p$ be morphisms such that $(p_0,p_1)t_0=(p_0,p_1)t_1$ and prove that $t_0=t_1$.

I then use the UMP of the product $A \times A$ in order to prove that there is a $\phi : T \rightarrow A \times A$ such that $p_0 t_0 = \pi_0 \phi$ and $p_1 t_1 = \pi_1 \phi$.

From here I don't know how to continue since I cannot see where/if I must use the UMP of the pullback at all?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to prove that $t_0=t_1$. But $t_0,t_1 : T \to R_p$ have a pullback as codomain. Your best bet is to use uniqueness in the UMP of $R_p$.

Meaning: try to find arrows $f,g : T \to A$ such that $pf=pg$ and such that
$$ p_0t_i = f, \quad p_1t_i = g \qquad \forall i \in \{0,1\}.$$

(If you draw a diagram with all your data, you'll see you don't really have a choice for $f$ and $g$.)

Comment: Thank you that seemed to help somewhat. I can define $a_0 = p_0 t_0$ and $a_1=p_1 t_0$ and use universal mapping property of those two and likewise for $a_0 '=p_0 t_1$ and $a_1 ' = p_1 t_1$ but how does that prove that $a_0 = a_0 '$ and $a_1 = a_1 '$?

Comment: @Bartuc : Try to express $p_0$ and $p_1$ in term of $(p_0,p_1)$.

Comment: Thank you Pece, I solved it by using your suggestion.